# Api calls from a fragment using Volley

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-volley

I am making API calls from my fragment and getting the response using volley. The API calls are made again every time I click on that fragment tab. I want the API call to take place only once. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried searching for the solution but did not find anything useful. Below is the code of my fragment.

```
public class Tab3News extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView newsView;
    private NewsAdapter newsadapter;
    String myxmlResponse;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Making request again","hello");
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3news, container, false);
        newsView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.newstable);
        String symPassed = ((SendString)getActivity()).message;

        String XmlURL = "http://demoapplication-env.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/?symbol="+symPassed+"&indicator=XML";


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, XmlURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //processData(response);

                            myxmlResponse = response;

                            newsView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            //newsView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                            newsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                            newsView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
                            newsadapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
                            newsView.setAdapter(newsadapter);

                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // handle error response
                    }
                }
        );
        queue.add(req);


        return layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep one boolean value in Preference and check its value everytime when this fragment is clicked.

Comment: Okay..didn't get exactly what you said. Totally new to android. In fact this is my first android app. Is it possible for you to elaborate ? Thanks!!

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer below, hope this will help you. There must be other ways also of doing this but currently i could think of this answer only, accept it, if this answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this-

1- Call the API from the parent activity of this fragment and accordingly pass the data to the fragment using '`setArguments(bundle)`', by doing this, your API would not get called everytime on loading of the fragment.

2- Keep a boolean value in the Preference whenever the API is called-

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        mMyPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isFirstTime = mMyPrefs.getBoolean("IS_FIRST_TIME", true);
       if (mIsFirstTime)
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = mMyPrefs.edit();
                        editPrefs.putBoolean("IS_FIRST_TIME", false);
                        editPrefs.apply();

                        callAPI();
                    }
      else
      {
             //TO DO YOUR STUFF
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to call the api in activity and pass the arguments through bundle rather than using a flag in shared preference. Then again, its  my personal opinion.